# how to send email using ajax in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, email

i'm trying to send email using ajax in laravel to stop reloading the page an send email , it stopped reloading the page correctly but it also stopped the form from sending email , that's the ajax code i wrote :

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(function(){
        $('#errorMsgs').hide();
        $('#sendmail').submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var first_name=$('input[name="first_name"]').val();
            var last_name=$('input[name="last_name"]').val();
            var client =$('input[name="client"]').val();
            var phone =$('input[name="phone"]').val();
            var address =$('input[name="address"]').val();
            var city=$('input[name="city"]').val();
            var telephone=$('input[name="telephone"]').val();
            var fax=$('input[name="fax"]').val();
            var service=$('input[name="service"]').val();
            var first=$('input[name="first"]').val();
            var how=$('input[name="how"]').val();

            var data = new FormData();
            data.append('first_name',first_name);
            data.append('last_name',last_name);
            data.append('client',client);
            data.append('phone',phone);
            data.append('address',address);
            data.append('city',city);
            data.append('telephone',telephone);
            data.append('fax',fax);
            data.append('service',service);
            data.append('first',first);
            data.append('how',how);

            $.ajax({
                url:'postIndex',
                type:'POST',
                data:data,
                processData:false,
                success:function(data){alert('Email sent successfully');},
                error:function(data){
                    $('#errorMsgs').show();
                    $('#errorMsgs').html('');

                    var errors=data.responseJSON;
                    $.each(errors,function(k,v){
                        $('#erroMsgs').append(v+"<br />");
                    });
                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

and that's how my route looks like :

```
Route::controller('request','MailController');
```

and that's the form i'm using :

```
<form class="row" id="sendmail" action="{{action('MailController@postIndex')}}" method="POST">
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                First Name: 
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="first_name" type="text" required>
                        </div><!--End col-sm-6-->
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Last Name:
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="last_name" type="text" required>
                        </div><!--End col-sm-6-->
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label>
                                Are you a new client?
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <select id="discuss" name="client" class="form-control" required>
                                <option selected value="yes , I am a potential new client">Yes, I am a potential new client.
                                    </option>
                                <option value="no , I am a current existing client">No, I am a current existing client.</option>
                                <option value="I'm neither.">I am neither.</option>
                            </select>
                        </div><!--End col-sm-12-->
                        <div class="spacer-25"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Phone Number:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="phone" type="text" required="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Email:
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="email" type="email" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Street Address:
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="address" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>City:</label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="city"  type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                            <label>Telephone
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control"  name="telephone" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>
                                Fax:
                            </label>
                            <input class="form-control" name="fax" type="text" required>
                        </div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Service Type:
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-4">
                                    <input checked="" name="service" id="residential" type="radio" value="residental service">
                                    <label for="residential">
                                        Residential
                                    </label>
                                </div><!--End col-sm-6-->
                                <div class="col-sm-5">
                                    <input checked="" name="service" id="ecommere" type="radio" value="commercial service">
                                    <label for="ecommere">
                                        ecommere
                                    </label>
                                </div><!--End col-sm-6-->  
                            </div><!--End Row-->
                        </div><!--End col-sm-6--> 
                        <div class="col-sm-6">
                            <label>Is this your first experience with spanah?:
                                <span class="required">
                                    *
                                </span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input checked="" name="first" id="yes-first" type="radio" value="yes it's my first experience">
                                    <label for="yes-first">
                                        yes
                                    </label>
                                </div><!--End col-sm-6-->
                                <div class="col-sm-3">
                                    <input checked="" name="first" id="no-first" type="radio" value="no it isn't my first experience">
                                    <label for="no-first">
                                        no
                                    </label>
                                </div><!--End col-sm-6-->  
                            </div><!--End Row-->
                        </div><!--End col-sm-6--> 
                        <div class="spacer-25"></div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <label>
                                How can spanah help you?
                            </label>
                            <textarea class="form-control" name="how" rows="5" required></textarea>
                        </div><!--End col-sm-12-->
                        <div class="custom-btn-container">
                            <button class="custom-btn" type="submit" name="submit">
                                Send Message
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="alert alert-success" id="errorMsgs"></div>
                    </form>
```

and that's postIndex function :

```
public function postIndex(){


    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $to = "elbiheiry2@gmail.com"; // this is your Email address
    $from = $_POST['email']; // this is the sender's Email address
    $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    $new=$_POST['client'];
    $phone=$_POST['phone'];
    $address=$_POST['address'];
    $city=$_POST['city'];
    $telephone=$_POST['telephone'];
    $fax=$_POST['fax'];
    $service=$_POST['service'];
    $first=$_POST['first'];
    $how=$_POST['how'];
    $subject = "Form submission";
    $subject2 = "Copy of your form submission";
    $message = $first_name . " " . $last_name . " wrote the following:". "\n\n" .$from . "\n\n" . $new .            "\n\n".$phone."\n\n".$address."\n\n".$city."\n\n".$telephone."\n\n".$fax."\n\n".$service."\n\n".$first."\n\n".$how;

    $headers="From:".$from;

    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

    return redirect()->action('MailController@getIndex');
    }
    }
```

so can anyone help me solving this problem ?

Comment: You have a lot of code in the question, could that not be reduced to make it easier for us? Anyhow, firstly, check the console for any errors and paste them in to the question if there are any errors.

Comment: there is no errors in the console and it gives me a message that it was sent but i didn't receive anything @Script47

Comment: postindex php code pls